# Implementing unique_unlock, the opposite of std::unique_lock

Tags: c++, synchronization, mutex

I have a situation where an std::mutex needs to be locked most of the time, except when inside a specific scope. I was thinking there should be an opposite of `std::unique_lock` that unlock()s on construction and the lock()s on destruction.
Should be something as simple as

```
template<typename M>
class unique_unlock
{
public:
    unique_unlock(M& m) : m_(m) {
        m_.unlock();
    }
    ~unique_unlock() {
        m_.lock();
    }
private:
    M& m_;
};
```

Is there any issue with this approach?

Comment: I can't see immediate issues except maybe a big potential for deadlocks. 
But that should be solved "by design". 
I would make the constructor "explicit" and delete all other constructors (default, copy, move) and remove the operator= too

Answer (score 2):

`std::mutex::lock` is documented to throw `std::system_error`, which would cause your **destructor** to throw. You need an explicit `noexcept(false)` to override the implicit `noexcept(true)`.

That's so unusual that you probably should also warn the users of your class about this. This appears to be a RAII scope guard class, but if this dtor runs during stack unwinding (as is the intent with RAII) then that second exception will `std::terminate` the program.

Comment: I'm wondering what actual real world scenarios are there for std::mutex::lock() to throw in common implementations and common OSs. Maybe in some extreme forms of resource starvation.